# Dropbox API Shared Folders

Tags: python, dropbox-api, shared-directory

Shared_folders is not DropboxClient attribute?? Then whose attribute is it??

why I get this error

'DropboxClient' object has no attribute 'shared_folders'

And how can I solve this?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201914129-shared-folders-api ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem too. I suspect the Python API hasn't been updated to support the somewhat new /shared_folders REST API call. I managed to use the rest_client directly to access the /shared_folders API. Here is some example Python code, assuming you already have a DropboxClient object in "client":

```
url, params, headers = client.request("/shared_folders/", {}, method='GET')
response = client.rest_client.GET(url, headers)
```

You can modify the target and params (first two args to client.request) based on the official [REST API documentation for /shared_folders](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shared-folders).